# Adding and trusting a cert to default OS X keychain with Ruby

Tags: ruby, ssl, command-line-interface

As part of setting up self-signed SSL on a local server I'd like to automate the steps to add a cert to the default keychain and set OS X's Keychain to "Always Trust" instead of "Use system defaults".

I've got the cert creation down and addition to the Keychain just fine but I can't seem to find the right flags to tell OS X to always trust the cert. Here's what I'm using:

```
def trust(cert)
  default_keychain = `security default-keychain`.chomp.strip.gsub '"', ''
  system "security -l add-trusted-cert -r trustRoot -p ssl -k #{default_keychain} #{cert_location}"
end
```

Since I'm not using the `-d` flag it's probably unnecessary to do the work in `default_keychain` but that's not the source of the issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was the wrong argument for the `-r` flag. `trustRoot` is used for root certificates, which is not the type of cert I'm supplying. Using `trustAsRoot` works as expected, always trusting the cert. This escalates `security` to needing the user password but I can live with that.